# What is the purpose of double precision drawing in Graphics2D

Tags: java, graphics2d

Could anybody explain it to me?

You can't draw between pixels so why should I use float or double measuring when drawing? In Oracle's docs is written something about printer device, but it also can't paint between the smallest points. I don't understand it.

Let's say a simple line. This line has set width 1.3f. What is going on with it when it's drawn on:

1. display in windows (I believe it has 96 DPI)?
2. printer with 300 DPI?

AFAIK Java uses 72 DPI internally. So how is the math?

Comment: Who says one unit corresponds to one pixel?  `Graphics2D` includes an arbitrary `AffineTransform` transformation that can scale values up by any factor you like.

Comment: Yes, but I could scale integer values as well.

Comment: Yes, but values like `0.1` could scale up to `5.0`, and then it doesn't matter if your double values were initially between integers; they're scaled up to full pixels now.

Comment: @LouisWasserman please look at the edited question above

Answer (score 0):

Several use cases come to mind.

- Your graphics device might be scaled. For example I know of several applications which draw a window-filling image of the unit circle, i.e. a circle of radius 1, using an appropiate scaling of the graphics context.
- You might be producing output for a vector-oriented target, like a PDF file. In that case, users might zoom in arbitrarily, and might expect a fair amount or precision even at high resolutions.
- Printers, like you mention, might print at a resolution much higher than the screen, which is accomplished by a built-in zoom factor that maps default coordinate units to several times the device pixel size.
- Anti-aliasing suggest sub-pixel resolution. The amount of color applied to a given pixel at the boundary of a geometric object will depend on the sub-pixel coordinates of said object.

None of the above would readily rule out using single precision floats, and in fact most G2D operations are available using floats as well. Using doubles is only important for really large zooms, really strong demands in terms of precision, and similar applications. But on the other hand, most computations are performed on doubles in any case, and the overhead of carrying these as far through the graphics pipeline as possible is often negligible. So when you ask me why to use double instead of float, I ask you “why not?”

Comment: Ok, but when I draw a circle of radius 5 using integer precision, what is the problem in the context of drawing it on printer where DPI is 300? Its just multiplied by 300/72, doesn't it? So it will be 20,8333333 => 21.